# Docker-compose exclude service by default

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have a great many services defined in a docker-compose project, how can I exclude a service from the default `docker-compose up` command?

For example, I have an nginx service, and an ssl service.  They conflict because they both consume port 80, so how can I make it so that the ssl service doesn't start unless I specifically run that service, and by default the `up` command will do everything EXCEPT the ssl service?

Comment: There were issues [#1294](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1294) and [#1896](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896) discussing this, but they were turned down by maintainers.

Answer (score 113):

Starting with [`docker-compose` 1.28.0](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.28.0) the new [service profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) are just made for that! With `profiles` you can mark services to be only started in specific profiles, for example:

```yaml
services:
  webapp:
    # ...

  nginx:
    # ...
    profiles: ["nginx"]
    ports:
      - 80:80

  ssl:
    # ...
    profiles: ["ssl"]
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

```sh
docker-compose up # start only your webapp services
docker-compose --profile nginx up # start the webapp and nginx service
docker-compose --profile ssl up # start the webapp and ssl service
docker-compose run ssl # run the ssl service
```

Depending on your exact use case/setup however it may be better to split your services into [multiple `docker-compose.yml` files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files).

Comment: NB: Services started via different profiles will be in different networks by default! https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: @MKesper: No, they won't. Services defined in the same compose file also use the same networks. Be sure to not confuse the [`--profile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/#use-profiles-to-enable-optional-services) with the [`--project-name`/`-p`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) flag - starting services using different project names actually _will_ result in separate networks^^

Answer (score 36):

Not exactly what you're looking for but you could use the [scale](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/) flag to scale your ssl service to zero:

```
docker-compose up --scale ssl_service=0
```

Another option is to have multiple compose files and run docker with the `-f` flag to start specific services.

Answer (score 24):

Hey I hit this question on github today:
"Define services which are not started by default"
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1896

Well, you can't. But I have done this workaround since I have quite a lot of services and adding more. I did dummy service with just some dummy image and custom command and then I set my desired services as dependencies:

```
  main-services:
    image: docker4w/nsenter-dockerd # you want to put there some small image
    command: sh -c "echo start"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - consumer-backend
      - prisma
      - api-gateway
      - adminer
      - frontend
```

Then I wrote into my readme.md:

Use this to run everything
`docker-compose up -d main-services`

Create database structures
`docker-compose up deploy`

Seed database with data
`docker-compose up seed`

Using dummy services to group things was easier than anything else I have seen so far.

Comment: it's really an elegant and simple solution