# How do I prevent my script from being run every time a Docker container is brought up?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, seeding, docker-entrypoint

I would to run a script (populate my MySql Docker container) only when my docker containers are built.  I'm running the following docker-compose.yml file, which contains a Django container.

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'maps_data'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'chicommons'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3406:3406"
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    ports:           # to access the container from outside
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn maps.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  apache:
    restart: always
    build: ./apache/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    #volumes:
    #  - web-static:/www/static
    links:
      - web:web

volumes:
  my-db:
```

I have this web/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install

RUN apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN mkdir -p /app/

WORKDIR /app/

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/
COPY . /app/
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/app/entrypoint.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and these are the contents of my entrypoint.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

python manage.py migrate maps
python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml
python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml

exec "$@"
```

The issue is, when I repeatedly run "docker-compose up," the entrypoint.sh script is getting run with its commands.  I would prefer the commands only get run when the docker container is first built but they seem to always get run when the container is restored.  Is there any way to adjust what I have to achieve this?

Comment: replace `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]` with `RUN /app/entrypoint.sh"`. Your script will be run on build.

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX That won’t work: you can’t access databases or other resources managed by Docker Compose during the build phase.

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX, unfortunately, that fails with a Django error, "KeyError: 'DB_NAME'" followed by "ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/app/entrypoint.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1."  "DB_NAME" is an environment variable defined in an ".env" file (at the same level as docker-compose.yml)

Comment: You can, however, put arbitrary code or logic into your entrypoint, so you “just” need to detect if the seed data is already there, and wrap the relevant loading steps into a Bourne shell `if ... fi` conditional.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, thx for this idea, since I didn't have any.  Is there a more standard way of doing something like this?  It doesn't seem like that odd of a request to me, but then again, I'm quite unfamiliar with Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach that I've used before is to wrap your `loaddata` calls in your own management command, which first checks if there's any data in the database, and if there is, doesn't do anything. Something like this:

```
# your_app/management/commands/maybe_init_data.py

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from address.models import Country

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if not Country.objects.exists():
            self.stdout.write('Seeding initial data')
            call_command('loaddata', 'maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml')
            call_command('loaddata', 'maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml')
```

And then change your entrypoint script to:

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py maybe_init_data
```

(Assumption here that you have a `Country` model - replace with a model that you do actually have in your fixtures.)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of seeding your database in the first run, is a very common case. As others have suggested, you can change your `entrypoint.sh` script and apply some conditioning logic to it and make it the way you want it to work.

But I think it is a really better practice if you separate the logic for `seeding the database` and `running services` and do not keep them tangled to each other. This might cause some unwanted behavior in the future.

I was going to suggest a workaround using `docker-compose` and started searching for some syntax for excluding some services while doing `docker-compose up` but found out this is still an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4133). But I found this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027899/3037529) witch has suggested a very nice approach.

```
version: '3'

services:
  all-services:
    image: docker4w/nsenter-dockerd # you want to put there some small image
    command: sh -c "echo start"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - web
      - apache

  mysql:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'maps_data'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'chicommons'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3406:3406"
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    ports:           # to access the container from outside
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn maps.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  apache:
    restart: always
    build: ./apache/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    #volumes:
    #  - web-static:/www/static
    links:
      - web:web

  seed:
    build: ./web
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    entrypoint: /bin/bash -c "/bin/bash -c \"$${@}\""
    command: |
      /bin/bash -c "
        set -e
        python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml
        python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
        /bin/bash || exit 0
      "
    depends_on:
      - mysql

volumes:
  my-db:
```

If you use something like above, you will be able to run `seeding` stage before running `docker-compose up`.

For seeding your databse, run:

```
docker-compose up seed
```

For running all your stack, use:

```
docker-compose up -d all-services
```

I think it is a clean approach and, can be extended to many different scenarios and use cases.

**UPDATE**

If you really want to be able to run the whole stack altogether and also prevent unexpected behaviors caused by running `loaddata` command multiple times, I would suggest you define a new django [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) to check for existing data. Look at this:

**checkseed.py**

```py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from project.models import Country  # or whatever model you have seeded

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Check if seed data already exists'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if Country.objects.all().count() > 0:
            self.stdout.write(self.style.WARNING('Data already exists .. skipping'))
            return False
        # do all the checks for your data integrity
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Nothing exists'))
        return True
```

And after this, you can change your `seed` part of `docker-compose` as below:

```
  seed:
    build: ./web
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    entrypoint: /bin/bash -c "/bin/bash -c \"$${@}\""
    command: |
      /bin/bash -c "
        set -e
        python manage.py checkseed &&
        python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml
        python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
        /bin/bash || exit 0
      "
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

This way, you can be sure that if anyone runs `docker-compose up -d` by mistake, will not cause integrity errors and problems like that.

Comment: I really like this idea of separating the seed stuff into a separate portion of the docker-compose file, but I have a couple of questions.  Before anything exists at all, you're saying I have to run "docker-compose up -d all-services" to build everything, then "docker-compose down" to stop stuff, then "docker-compose up seed" to seed what I just built, then "docker-compose up" to bring everything up again?

Comment: I think you just need to first run `docker-conpose up seed` and after that, run `docker-conpose up -d all-services`. You see, in thr first step, a container will be created and after running the commands related to seeding, the container will stop running and close. So you wouldn't need to worry about any leftovers.

Comment: If I were to just run "docker-conpose up" without "-d all-services," what would get run?

Comment: I think you want to keep `-d` part of the command. If you were to run `docker-compose up -d`, a scenario very similar to what you have right now (without my suggested changes) will be run. Technically, if you just run `docker-compose up -d`, your whole stack + a dummy container (with `docker4w/nsenter-dockerd` image) will get deployed. Plus, one container will start and exit right after doing its job.

Comment: Unfortunately I fear people don't read documentation and some folks are going to run "docker-compose up" and that is why I'm asking what will happen if they do that.

Comment: Nothing unexpected and awful would happen. Worst case, the seeding command will get run against your database.

Comment: Gotcha.  So then would it be possible to rewrite that "seed:" portion such that it woudl only run the seeding command if seeding hadn't already been done?  You probably see what I'm trying to do.  If "docker-compose up" were run multiple times, I would only want it to perform the seeding action the first time.

Comment: @Dave I have updated the answer to fit all your needs.

Comment: Thanks for that update.  So another follow-up, given what you have, why would I even need an extra "seed" definition in my docker-compose.yml file?  Couldn't I just make your Python command part of the entrypoint.sh file?  And if that's true, is your answer then the same as @solarissmoke's answer?

Comment: This would be slightly different from @solarissmoke's answer. But yeah, that would do the job too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `entrypoint.sh` file, why not just run the commands in the web/Dockerfile?

```
RUN python manage.py migrate maps
RUN python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml
RUN python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
```

That way these changes will be baked into the image and, when you start the image, these changes will already have been executed.

Comment: Thanks but this results in an error, "KeyError: 'DB_NAME', ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py migrate maps' returned a non-zero code: 1"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case recently. As the "ENTRYPOINT" contains the command that will be executed every time the container starts a solution would be to include some logic on the **entrypoint.sh** script in order to avoid to apply the updates ( in your case the migration and the load of the data ) if the **effects** of these operations are already present on the database.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

#Function that goes to verify if effects of migration and load data are present on database
function checkEffects() {
  IS_UPDATED=0
  #Check effects and set to 1 IS_UPDATED if effects are not present
}

checkEffects
if [[ $IS_UPDATED == 0 ]]
then
   echo "Database already initialized. Nothing to do"
else
   echo "Database is clean. Initializing it"
   python manage.py migrate maps
   python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml
   python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
fi

exec "$@"
```

However **the scenario is more complex** because to verify the effects that allow to decide if to proceed or not with the updates can be a quite difficult if these involves multiple data and data. 
Moreover it becomes very complex if you think on the containers upgrade over time.

> **Example:** Today you're working with a local Dockerfile for your **web** service but I think in production you'll start to versioning this service uploading it on a Docker registry. So when you'll upload
>   your first release ( for example the **1.0.0 version** ) you'll
>   specify the following on your docker-compose.yml:
>
> ```
> web:
>    restart: always
>    image: <DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST>:<DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT>/web:1.0.0 
>    ports: # to access the container from outside
>      - "8000:8000"
> ```
>
> Then you'll release the "1.2.0" version of the **web** service
>   container when you'll include other changes on the schema for example
>   loading other data on **entrypoint.sh**:
>
> ```
> #1.0.0 updates  
> python manage.py migrate maps 
> python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml 
> python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/seed_data.yaml
> #1.2.0 updates   
> python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/other_seed_data.yaml
> ```
>
> Here you'll have 2 scenarios (
>   **let's ignore for now the need to check for effects on the script** ):
>
> **1- You deploy for the first time your services with *web:1.2.0***: As you start from a clean database you should be sure that **all**
>   updates are executed ( both *1.1.0* and *1.2.0* ).
>
> *The solution to this case is easy because you can just execute all updates.*
>   **2- You upgrade web container to *1.2.0* on an existing environment where *1.0.0* was running**: As your database has been initialized
>   with updates from 1.0.0 you should be sure that **only *1.2.0***
>   updates are executed
>
> *Here is difficult because you should be able to check what is the version on database applied in order to skip 1.0.0 updates. This will
>   means you should store the web version somewhere on database for
>   example*

As per all this discussion so I think the best solution is to work directly on  scripts that goes to create schema and populate data in order to make these instructions idempotent paying attention on upgrade ones.

Some examples:

**1- Create a table**

Instead to create table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE country
```

use the *if not exists* to avoid **table already present** error:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country
```

**2- Insert default data**

Instead to insert data without primary key specified:

```
INSERT INTO maps.country (name) VALUES ("USA");
```

Include *primary key* in order to avoid **duplicates**:

```
INSERT INTO maps.country (id,name) VALUES (1,"USA");
```

Comment: The CREATE SQL is genreated using Django's migration process and the INSERTs are run through the "python manage.py loaddata maps/fixtures/country_data.yaml".  How do I do what you say keeping the Django and Python conventions?

Comment: You’ve assigned the bounty and confirmed another answer as correct. Didn’t it solved the issue completely? If not, I can try to see in details this for Django

Answer (score 0):

Usually **build** and **deploy** steps are separated.

Your `ENTRYPOINT` is part of **deploy**. 
If you want configure manually witch deploy run should run migrate commands and witch just replace containers by a new one (maybe from fresh image), then you can slit it into a separate commands

start database (if not running)

```
docker-compose -p production -f docker-compose.yml up mysql -d
```

migrate

```
docker run \
        --rm \
        --network production_default \
        --env-file docker.env \
        --entrypoint python \
        my-backend-image-name:prod python manage.py migrate maps
```

and then deploy fresh image

```
docker-compose -p production -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

And each time manually decide should you run migrate step or not

Comment: I'm happy to move the seeding of the database into a build phase (as opposed to a deploy phase), but then does that mean "docker-compose up" is doing both a build and deploy each time it is run?

Comment: no, for build you should call 
docker-compose -p production -f docker-compose.yml build

Comment: But if "docker-compose up" doesn't build anything, why do I see images downloaded in the docker console and then I'm able to access my services on the various ports?

Comment: It use images that available at the host (if you have image: in yml for service) and in case of no image at host it pulls image from repo and in case no "image:" in yml it builds according to "build:"